# Very confused on how stacking context works

Tags: html, css

This is a simplified version of my code but it's enough to demonstrate the problem.
What I want to achieve is ::before pseudo element behind the  element. So I should have my green footer, the red pseudo element and on top the span text.
If you try run this code in your browser you'll notice that the footer element covers the ::before pseudo element, but why?
Should't z-index -1 be relative to the pseudo element parent, in this case the  element?
How can I solve?

```css
footer {
  background: green;
}

footer a {
  position: relative;
}

footer a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">
    <span>FB</span>
  </a>
</footer>
```

Comment: I don't understand enough, so I can't explain, but setting `isolation: isolate;` on the `a` element should work.

Answer (score 2):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context) which lists a large number of things that can create a new stacking context, but none of them apply to your `<a>` element.

The closest one is:

> Element with a position value absolute or relative and z-index value other than auto.

Your `<a>` is `position: relative` but you haven't changed the `z-index` away from `auto` so it doesn't create a new stacking context.

Consequently, the `::before` psuedo-element's stacking context is the root element.

---

Setting the `z-index` gives the effect you expect (as will changing it in one of the many other ways listed on the above link):

```css
footer {
  background: green;
}

footer a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

footer a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a href="#">
    <span>FB</span>
  </a>
</footer>
```